# Playframework - how to implement Reads for list?

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a custom reads I am using, which looks like this:

```
def myReads(companyId: Long): Reads[MyClass] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] and
    Reads.pure(companyId)
  ) (MyClass.apply _)
```

I am trying to read a List of MyClass, and I am not sure how.
So if I wanted to read only one MyClass I did it like this by providing my reads:

```
request.body.validate[MyClass](MyClass.myReads(100)).fold(e => , valid => )
```

The thing is I want to read a list of MyClass so I tried something like this:

```
request.body.validate[List[MyClass]](( __ \ "list").read[List[MyClass]](MyClass.myReads(100)).fold()
```

But it expect Reads for list, not sure how to fix it.
Have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reads must be

```
request.body.validate[List[MyClass]](
  ( __ \ "list").read[List[MyClass]](
    Reads.list(MyClass.myReads(100))
  )
).fold()
```